# How to edit the hover color of button in the header of Carena theme in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

There isn't any option to do so in the Customize theme menu of Wordpress and King Composer isn't as user-friendly as Elementor for a beginner like me. I just want to change the hover color of the right button on the header.

Comment: The "enquire" button ?

Comment: If I'm right about this button ...
I saw the css and it doesn't have an id or class which makes it different from other buttons. Its class is "btn btn-primary" like the others, if you change the hover of this button, all the other buttons will change too.

You need to modify the theme: find the file where this button is located, add a class or id to it and modify its css.

Comment: Changing the theme is not a good idea because you will loose changes on updating it and if you don't update it you could be open to vulnerabilities. I would look at the parent elements and try to channel down the css such as "header .btn {}" for example. I haven't got this theme so I can not give you the exact css code